# Run TestNG suite from maven getting error:maven-surefire-plugin:test failed: testSuiteXmlFiles0 has null value

Tags: java, maven, testng

I see a lot of posts on here about running a TestNG suite using Maven surefire plugin. The examples say to add this to the pom:

```
<configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>${testSuite}</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
</configuration>
```

And then this to the command line:

```
mvn test -DtestSuite=myCustomSuite.xml
```

My problem with this is that it ties you to using the TestNG suite... For example, if I want to run with groups like this:

```
mvn test -Dgroups=myGroup
```

I get this error:

> maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: testSuiteXmlFiles0 has null value

I want to be able to run, from command line, passing in either a suite path or groups.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using your surefire configuration with a property, you can:

1. Remove the surefire configuration and replace `mvn test -DtestSuite=myCustomSuite.xml` by `mvn test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=myCustomSuite.xml`. See [Surefire documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#suiteXmlFiles)
2. Continue to use the `mvn test -Dgroups=myGroup`.

As the surefire configuration will be removed, the error `testSuiteXmlFiles0 has null value` won't be present with the `-Dgroup` option.

You can also use maven profiles which will configure surefire plugin depending on which property you pass to maven.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>suite</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>testSuite</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
          <suiteXmlFile>${testSuite}</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Done, but I found a better solution

Comment: I just tried this and it does not work when using -Dgroups... please read the question before giving an answer.

Comment: Did you remove your surefire configuration too?

Comment: Ok, that works... thanks. I'll accept your answer and upvote it.

Comment: @juherr Thanks! Yes its worked for given error,  I am able to now call xml with desired location. It worked fine.  mvn test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles="./XML File/testngdemo.xml"

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the accepted answer didn't work for me. I used something like following.

```
mvn test -Dgroups=myGroup -DtestSuite=" "
```